# Checking the solution to a diffential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a quick way to check that the solution to a diffential equation is correct, I know you can diffentiate it and see if it works but this can take a long time (I want to check my answers in an exam and hense time is not in plentful supply). Hense is there are shorter way? Just for an example to check that $(e^{-t})(Acos(2t)+Bsin(2t))$ is the correct genral solution fo $y^{\prime \prime} + 2y^{\prime} +5y=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to plug it into the differential equation. Does the solution satisfy the differential equation?

Comment: Yes but is there a quicker ways as with examples more complicated then this, it can be a long method and time consuming?

Comment: If you are just dealing with linear homogenous differential equations, you can always double check your eigenvalues using a calculator or WolframAlpha. Honestly, you could plug your differential equation in. Other than that, there really aren't faster ways to check.